# Maven Release Plugin - release:branch - Version Parameter in -DbranchName

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When executing the `mvn release:branch` command, I'd like to try and configure the `-DbranchName` argument with a version parameter.  But I haven't been able to find a way to successfully do this yet.

For example, if I have a project in trunk with version 1.0-SNAPSHOT, I want to create a branch using the `--batch-mode` option and specify a `-DbranchName` with the current project version (1.0-SNAPSHOT) as a parameter in the within the branchName.

I've tried doing `mvn release:branch -DbranchName=VERSION-@{project.version}`, but it doesn't seem to work as I had hoped.  Instead of creating a branch with the name VERSION-1.0, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:branch (default-cli) on project project-a: Unable to branch SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn branch command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E205000: Try 'svn help copy' for more information
[ERROR] svn: E205000: Syntax error parsing peg revision '{project.version}'
```

Is there a valid way to do this?  Or is this not possible when doing a `release:branch` with the maven release plugin?

### Edit

Basically what I'm looking for is something similar to the `tagNameFormat` property but for branches.  When doing a `release:perform` goal, I can have `<tagNameFormat>VERSION-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>` specified in the pom, and I don't need to include any tag name property when doing a release using `--batch-mode`.  Is there any similar property for formatting of branch names when doing a `release:branch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in `${project.version}` (prefixed with `$` instead of `@` -- the latter seems only available in the `tagNameFormat` parameter). Note that if you use `${project.version}`, the value will probably contain the substring `SNAPSHOT` in it. There may be several ways of removing that substring. One way is to apply the helper plugin mentioned in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347796/manipulate-project-version-property-to-remove-snapshot) which gives you access to the version's semantic components:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>parse-version</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>parse-version</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you can use the properties on the command line:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=VERSION-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}
```

Or better to include the `branchName` parameter as part of the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <branchName>VERSION-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}</branchName>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>branch</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this case you don't need to pass these magic properties on the command line.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!